# Converting svg to pdf: Why am I losing my text?

Tags: pdf, svg, batik

I'm using Batik to convert an svg to a pdf.  The pdf that Batik outputs has no text.  The svg does have text.  If I use Batik to rasterize to png, I do get text.

The font I am using is Arial.  I am on a debian box.  Arial is installed.  Here is the command I am using:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /usr/local/share/java/batik-1.7/batik-rasterizer.jar \
    -m application/pdf -bg 255.255.255.255 -d /tmp/olV0zQ_wYQ/chart.pdf \ 
    /tmp/tAi25KAE2z/tmp.svg
```

And then I get the following output:

```
About to transcode 1 SVG file(s)

Converting tmp.svg to /tmp/olV0zQ_wYQ/chart.pdf ... ... success
```

Here is my [svg file](http://nopaste.me/paste/20970750674ec39721abe26).

Comment: Are you able to post the SVG?

Comment: Hmm... it converts just fine for me. Can you post the PDF that it generates?

Comment: i cannot open the url of your svg - does it work for anybody else ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.
It worked fine on the local machine but not on a distant server (debian).
I solved it by repositionning the text (the font was there but was out of view)

Please try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="330" viewBox="0 0 500 300">

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
.xAxisLabels
{
color: #000000;
font-family: Arial
}
]]></style>
<title>title</title>
<desc>stuff</desc>
<defs>
    <font-face font-family="Arial">
        <font-face-src>
        <font-face-uri xlink:href="/usr/share/hholdings/fonts/Arial.ttf"/>
        </font-face-src>
    </font-face>
</defs>

<text transform="translate(112.5 300)" class="xAxisLabels">jan</text>
<text transform="translate(204.17 300)" class="xAxisLabels">feb</text>
<text transform="translate(295.84 300)" class="xAxisLabels">mar</text>
<text transform="translate(387.51 300)"  class="xAxisLabels">apr</text>
</svg>
```